# filter nested array of objects based on object values Javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, filter

I am trying to filter below array of objects against `search` variable which is a string. So, user can search based on title, year or name of people

```
array = [{
    "title": "Test",
    "year": 2018,
    "people": [
      {
        "name": "person1"
      },
      {
        "name": "person2"
      }],
  },
  {
    "title": "Test2",
    "year": 2018,
    "people": [
      {
        "name": "person3"
      },
      {
        "name": "person4"
      },
      {
        "name": "person5"
      }],
   },...]
```

I have written the below function which works fine for *title* and *year* but I could not figure out how to search the *people* array inside the function. I know how to do it without ES6 but I prefer ES6 which is still confusing to me:

```
filteredArray() {
            let search = this.search.toLowerCase();
            return this.array.filter(function (item) {
                    return Object.values(item).some(val =>
                        String(val).toLowerCase().includes(search));
            })
        },
```

`this.search` is the `v-model` that holds the value user types in.
Here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/djshan/pen/zYOMKgW)

I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code helps your usecase

```
   var searchString = 'person5';

   let result = array.filter(ele => 
    ele.title.includes(searchString)
    || `${ele.year}`.includes(searchString)
    || ele.people.some(pele => pele.name.includes(searchString))
   )
   console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Why use `.filter(...).length > 0` instead of `.some(...)`?

Comment: @Barmer Yes thats even better, updated the answer using `.some()`

Comment: Thank you @karthikdivi for your response. it works for year but it does not work for title and people.

Comment: @DjSh I have tested for all three cases, you can run and see it here https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3v2t9b96g

Comment: I just ran it on your example and this is the results `people: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]` which shows it does not work

Comment: @DjSh ahh, that was just a logging issue, I have updated my code, please re-run and see

Answer (score 0):

Create a Map/hash of search strings to easily search:

```js
const array = [{
"title": "Test",
"year": 2018,
"people": [
  {
    "name": "person1"
  },
  {
    "name": "person2"
  }],
  },
  {
"title": "Test2",
"year": 2018,
"people": [
  {
    "name": "person3"
  },
  {
    "name": "person4"
  },
  {
    "name": "person5"
  }],
   }];


let map = array.reduce((map,item,i)=>{
  let values = Object.values(item);
  let persons = values.pop().map(e=>e.name);
  [...values,...persons].forEach(e=>map.set(String(e).toLowerCase(),i))
  return map;
},new Map());

//console.log(...map);
['person1','person3','Test2'].forEach(e=>console.log({[e]:array[map.get(String(e).toLowerCase())]}))
```

For Vue, try

```
filteredArray() {
    let search = this.search.toLowerCase();
    let arr2d = this.arr2d;
    if(typeof arr2d ==="undefined"){
     arr2d = this.array.reduce((arr,item)=>{
      let values = Object.values(item);
      let persons = values.pop().map(e=>e.name);
      arr.push([...values,...persons]);
      return arr;
     },[]);
    }
    return this.array.filter((item,i)=>arr2d[i].some(el=>
        String(el).toLowerCase().includes(search)))
    }
```

Comment: would you please help me understand your code. I have provided a codepen. I dont understand how to apply it there

Comment: @DjSh I've made a attempt for vue. The basic strategy is to reduce the main array of objects to array of arrays and store it(`arr2d`).  This `arr2d` will contain list of strings in the same index like [['item','person1','person2',2018],['item2','person3','person4',....]]. This way, you can easily filter everything.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help. I had to modify your code for it work. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/djshan/pen/pozQOXN). there was no need for the if statement( bcs of the way you initialized arr2d).

Comment: @DjSh I wanted to make `arr2d` permanent and not to be calculated on each search type in. The way you've initialized it, it'll calculate arr2d again and  again from the same publications again and again for each search letter. I want that part of the calculations outside the `filteredArray()` method if possible. It should be calculated only on new entry of publications.